# Asynchronous subscriber in Google PubSub with Async library

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, google-cloud-pubsub, async.js

As we know, Google PubSub javascript library is asynchronous (publisher and subscriber are asynchronous). From what I read, we can't make the execution of subscriber async in JS code because JS is single-threaded.

- Can someone explain me how it actually works when I subscribe on the event 'message'?
- If I receive 5 messages consecutively, will my MessageHandler block until it's done?
- How can I handle the messages asynchronously in JS ? I heard about using a queue (with one worker in parallel) with async library. How does it works then, in comparison without it ?

Thank you in advance for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

The execution is asynchronous, but the single-threaded nature of Javascript means that only one of the async callbacks executes at a time. When you subscribe on the event 'message,' every incoming message will trigger the event to run your callback with the incoming message. These will be queued up and run one at a time. Each call will block until it completes.

The best way to achieve parallel processing of messages with Javascript is going to be to start up multiple instances of your subscriber. When there are multiple subscribers receiving messages from the same subscription, Cloud Pub/Sub load balances the messages, sending a subset of messages to each subscriber.

If you only want to run a single instance, then you have a few, albeit suboptimal choices. First, if you want to split up the work across multiple iterations through the event loop, then you can use `setImmediate` to tell the engine to run the provided callback in the next iteration of the event loop. For example:

```
const doExpensiveWork = message => {
  // Do some more expensive processing here.
  message.ack();
}

const messageHandler = message => {
  console.log(`Received message: ${message.id}`);
  // Do some work on message here.
  setImmediate(() => doExpensiveWork(message));
};

subscription.on('message', messageHandler);
```

This would allow you to make some progress on messages simultaneously, though blocks of execution will still happen serially.

If you want parallel processing across different cores in the processor with a single instance of your service running, you'll need to [fork subprocesses](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster).

Comment: Thank you for your time, your answer is very helpful! Yes I would prefer to use a single instance, but is the solution with async queue and 1 worker (https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#queue) another way to handle them asynchronously ?

Comment: Another question, if the call is blocking, and the handler still receives a lot of messages, will the stack crash and the messages be lost (bottleneck?) ?

Comment: The async library won't run the code on multiple cores simultaneously. It's limited to single-threaded execution without the use of forking child processes. The async library just makes it easier to set up asynchronous executions that need to run and possibly be aggregated. 

Receiving an overwhelming number of messages could cause the task to crash, but [flow control](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#config), which allows you to restrict the number of simultaneous outstanding messages, helps. Either way, if your task crashes, the messages will be redelivered when it starts back up.